# AxiosError 500 when deploying to railway.app

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, axios

I am creating an api using nodejs expressjs and cheerio and axios.
My code works absolutely fine on localhost but when i deploy it on railway.app and other deploying sites. I receive Axios Error 500. I will mention the error at bottom of this post.
The thing is upon deployment, the code doesn't goes past this line
const {data} = await axios.get(url)
My code:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { log } from "console";
import axios from "axios";
import cheerio from "cheerio";
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

async function flipkart(title,resultArray)
{
    let p_names = [], prices = [], reviews = [], desc = [], urls = [], trs = [];
    console.log("Im flippkart");
    let webs = "https://www.flipkart.com"
    let url = `https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=${title}`
    const {data} =await axios.get(url)
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const review_divs = $('._1YokD2  ._3LWZlK');
    const product_divs = $("._4rR01T")
    const prices_div = $("._1_WHN1")
    const desc_div = $(".fMghEO")
    const p_url = $("._1fQZEK")
    const total_reviews = $('span._2_R_DZ span span:contains("Reviews")');
    product_divs.each((idx,x) => {
        p_names.push($(x).text());
    });
    prices_div.each((idx,x) => {
        prices.push($(x).text());
    });  
    review_divs.each((idx,x) => {

        reviews.push($(x).text());
    });
    desc_div.each((idx,x) => {
        desc.push($(x).text());
    });
    total_reviews.each((idx,x) => {
        trs.push($(x).text());
    });
    p_url.each((idx,x) => {
        urls.push(webs+$(x).attr("href"));
    });
    const extractNumbers = (str) => {
        const matches = str.match(/\d+/g); // Updated regular expression to include commas
        return matches ? parseInt(matches.join(''), 10) : null;
    };
    let trs_real= trs.map(extractNumbers);
    const tempresultArray = p_names.map((product, index) => ({
        title: product,
        url: urls[index],
        total_review_count: parseInt(trs_real[index],10),
        price: parseFloat(prices[index].replace(/[,₹]/g, '')),
        rating: parseFloat(reviews[index]),
        description: desc[index],
        website: webs
    }));
    for(let i = 0; i<tempresultArray.length; i++)
    {
        resultArray.push(tempresultArray[i]);
    }
}
async function shopclues(p_names, prices, reviews, desc, urls, trs)
{
    console.log("Im shopclues");
    let webs = "https://www.shopclues.com"
}
async function snapdeal(p_names, prices, reviews, desc, urls, trs)
{
    console.log("Im snapdeal");
    let webs = "https://www.snapdeal.com"
}
app.get("/do", async (req, res) => {
    let title = req.query.title;
    let filter = req.query.filter;
    let topN = req.query.topN;
    let website = req.query.website;
    let resultArray = [];
    console.log(title,filter,topN);
    console.log(website);
    if(typeof website === 'string') website = [website]
    if(website === undefined ) website = ['flipkart','snapdeal','shopclues']
    if(website.length == 1 && website[0]=="") website = ['flipkart','snapdeal','shopclues']
    console.log(website);
    for(let i = 0; i<website.length; i++)
    {
        if(website[i] == 'flipkart') await flipkart(title,resultArray)
        else if(website[i] == 'snapdeal') await snapdeal(title,resultArray);
        else if(website[i] == 'shopclues') await shopclues(title,resultArray)
    }
    
    const obj = {
        products: resultArray,
        total_products_considered: resultArray.length
    }
    if(filter == 'lp') obj.products.sort((a,b)=> a.price - b.price);
    else if(filter == 'hp') obj.products.sort((a,b)=> b.price - a.price);
    else if(filter == 'hreview') obj.products.sort((a,b)=> b.total_review_count - a.total_review_count);
    else if(filter == 'hrating') obj.products.sort((a,b)=> b.rating - a.rating);
    let n = parseInt(topN,10)

    obj.products.splice(n);

    const myobj = JSON.stringify(obj);
    res.send(myobj)
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Error:

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 500",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n    at settle (file:///app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:12)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (file:///app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:585:11)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:529:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "User-Agent": "axios/1.6.2",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
        },
        "method": "get",
        "url": "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone13"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE",
    "status": 500
}
```

I have uploaded my project on github and i'm using this github repo to host it on railway.app

1. [Github Link](https://github.com/amanrubey/scraperealdemo)

The API is such that you have to provide query parameters title, website, topN, filter.
For simplicity sake don't use values other than the ones provided in link. Because it might not be able to scrape this data from flipkart.com. Like certain keyword like "samsung" is not scrapeable ( I have yet not added the logic, since the divs in that html page had different class as the layout is kinda different for samsung when compared to iphone13,iphone14 etc).
Rest assured these values works absolutely fine for localhost.

Comment: FYI: There's often no need to use Axios in modern Node.js development as the web standard [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is available in Node.js from version 16.15. It provides [a number of benefits](https://blog.logrocket.com/fetch-api-node-js/) over using 3rd party packages. [Read more about it](https://www.codewithyou.com/blog/finally-we-can-use-fetch-api-in-nodejs).